# PHP Multiple update records

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql-update, dreamweaver

PHP Multiple update records not working
This program can update multiple records but only one rows, is there something have to fix or to add to make it work?
i need help please...
tnx

this is the code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/tlsc_conn.php'); ?>
<?php
$maxRows_Recordset1 = 10;
$pageNum_Recordset1 = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_Recordset1'])) {
  $pageNum_Recordset1 = $_GET['pageNum_Recordset1'];
}
$startRow_Recordset1 = $pageNum_Recordset1 * $maxRows_Recordset1;

mysql_select_db($database_tlsc_conn, $tlsc_conn);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM tb_exam";
$query_limit_Recordset1 = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_Recordset1, $startRow_Recordset1, $maxRows_Recordset1);
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_limit_Recordset1, $tlsc_conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);

?>
```

Comment: Change header("location:mulupdate.php"); do die("re-opening mulupdate.php") to see if this is not is opening your web page in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

remove this and see if it is better

```
if($row_Recordset1){
header("location:mulupdate.php");
exit;
}
```

and in the form action, set it as

```
action="mulupdate.php"
```

Comment: it's runs,but also not updating my records in rows,what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Where is `$submit` set? If it's not set then your update will never run and the value of `$row_Recordset1` will always be the result of your `SELECT` query. This means in turn that the `header()` statement will redirect immediately.

If the redirection is to the same page you will have the loop.

You probably need `$submit = $_GET['submit']` at the top of your code and later use

```
if($submit){
  for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name[$i]', lastname='$lastname[$i]',   email='$email[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]'";
    $row_Recordset1=mysql_query($sql1);
  }

  // note: this moved inside if($submit) block
  if($row_Recordset1){ 
    header("location:mulupdate.php");
    exit;
  }
}
```

(I haven't tested this so the logic might need a tweak)

Comment: $submit is the button submit (so it is set if someone goes to the page cliking on that button)

Comment: No - $submit is just a variable. You need `$_GET['submit']`

Comment: i try to add the variables, use the $submit = $_GET['submit']; but its consistent, not updating... :(

Answer (score 1):

Variables are not set either:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastname= $_POST['lastname'];
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and it should work for you

```
<?php 
 require_once('Connections/tlsc_conn.php');
 mysql_select_db($database_tlsc_conn, $tlsc_conn);

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $count = count($_POST['name']);

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
          $sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name[$i]',lastname='$lastname[$i]', email='$email[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]'";
        $row_Recordset1=mysql_query($sql1);
    }

    if($row_Recordset1){
            header("location:mulupdate.php");
            exit;
    }   
 }

 $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name";
 $Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $tlsc_conn) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form2" method="post" action="">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <table width="634" border="1">
    <tr>
       <td>id</td>
       <td>name</td>
       <td>lastname</td>
       <td>email</td>
    </tr>
    <?php while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php $id[]=$row_Recordset1['id']; ?><?php echo $row_Recordset1['id'];      ?></td>
      <td><input name="name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['name'];   ?>"></td>
       <td><input name="lastname[]" type="text" value="<?php echo   $row_Recordset1['lastname']; ?>"></td>
       <td><input name="email[]" type="text" value="<?php echo  $row_Recordset1['email']; ?>">
       </td>
    </tr>
     <?php } ?>

   </table>
   <p>
    <label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
     </label>
   </p>
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, but still not working :( , and why did you total_row the query?

Comment: I have put the update code at the top and running the SELECT statement below it. When you load the page the first time it will display all the records for you and when you click on Submit button it will run the update query and then redirect to the mulupdate.php script. What problem are you facing now?

Comment: I've been try it, but gets my "first row" blank the record when i submit it, and the remaining rows are still there, and the record of my "first row" is still on my database, why should it happening?

Comment: i'm so sorry for the disturbance, but that code didn't show the all records.but tnx for helping me to this...but i'm trying to solve it now.but if you determine why the records not showing.please tell me...